# log_ecs_reformatting not reformatting

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-apm

I'm trying to monitor my Spring Boot logs with Elasticsearch, and currently, the logs are successfully being generated with the "trace.id". However, it displays "failed to find message in logs files". When I give the below property in JSON format, logs are written to my local log path, but it won't write when deployed on an Ubuntu server.

"log_ecs_reformatting=OVERRIDE"

The errors currently showing in my log file suggest there might be issues. Do you have any ideas on how to resolve this?